# How to define a Java Script method inside a Java Script constructor

Tags: javascript, html

So I would like to have a method inside my constructor. I call my constructor like this

```
new EnhancedTooltip($("taskPreview1"))
```

and define it as so

```
///<var> Represents the controls</var>
var EnhancedTooltip = function (toolTipObject) {

    ///<field name="alignment" type="Number">.</field>
    this.alignment = 2;
    ///<field name="associatedControl" type="Number">.</field>
    this.associatedControl = toolTipObject;
    ///<field name="caption" type="Number">.</field>
    this.caption = "Let's see how this works";
    ///<field name="description" type="Number">.</field>
    this.description;
    ///<field name="enableEffects" type="Number">.</field>
    this.enableEffects = false;
    ///<field name="fadeAnimationSpeed" type="Number">.</field>
    this.fadeAnimationSpeed = 500;
    ///<field name="image" type="Number">.</field>
    this.image;
    ///<field name="minimumHeight" type="Number">.</field>
    this.minimumHeight = 100;
    ///<field name="minimumWidth" type="Number">.</field>
    this.minimumWidth = 200;
    ///<field name="objectName" type="String">.</field>
    this.objectName = $("taskToolTip");
    ///<field name="padding" type="Number">.<field>
    this.padding = 5;
    ///<field name="tailAngle" type="Number">.</field>
    this.tailAngle;
    ///<field name="tailDiamensions" type="Object">.</field>
    this.tailDimensions = new Size(15, 0);

    EnhancedTooltip.init();

    this.init = new function () {
      ///<summary>Initializes the class EnhancedTooltip.<summary>

      console.log(EnhancedToolTip.objectName);
    };

  };
```

and getting the error that EnhancedTooltip has no method init. So how should I define init.

Also if I want to call other functions from init how would I do that. For example

```
this.addToolTipElements = function() {

    $("#workspaceContainer").append("<div id = taskToolTip class = taskToolTip</div>");

    this.objectName.append("<canvas id = toolTipCanvas class = toolTipCanvas </canvas>");


    this.objectName.append("<div id = toolTipCaption class = toolTipCaption>" + this.caption + "</div>");

 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because "EnhancedTooltip" is your constructor function, and it doesn't have an "init" property. However, the object being constructed (`this`) does:

```
this.init();
```

and inside the function:

```
  console.log(this.objectName);
```

Also, it's not `new function`, it's just `function`:

```
this.init = function() {
  console.log(this.objectName);
};
```

*edit* ah and, as Sirko points out, call the function *after* defining it.

Comment: Now if i wanted to call functions from init how would i do that

Comment: When you call "init" like this: `this.init();`, or from the outside: `myTooltip.init();`, then `this` *inside* the function will refer to your object instance. Thus, you can always access the methods you've set up in the constructor or on the object's prototype via `this` - `this.someMethod();` etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a function expression, you can't rely on variable hoisting here.

Just define the method, before calling it like this:

```
// rest of the code    

///<field name="tailDiamensions" type="Object">.</field>
this.tailDimensions = new Size(15, 0);

this.init = new function () {
  ///<summary>Initializes the class EnhancedTooltip.<summary>

  console.log(this.objectName);
};

this.init();
```

On a sidenote, you should only reference to your object by using `this` inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you call `init()` method **before** you declare it.

And the second thing is — try to use better style for declaring Clases.

For example, I prefer [this](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling init wrong. You defined it in the `this` scope and not the prototype, so EnhancedToolTip does not have this function before being created. Try this:

```
var EnhancedTooltip = function (toolTipObject) {
  [..]

  this.init = new function () {
    ///<summary>Initializes the class EnhancedTooltip.<summary>
    console.log(this);
  };

  this.init();
};
```